# SQL query for top entries using multiple columns

Tags: sql, sqlite

I’ve got a Sqlite Database I want to query. My basic SQL Knowledge enables me to query for most I need but I’m stuck here:

The table looks like this (simplified!):

```
| Name            | Year | Title   | Musician 1 | Musician 2  |
| --------------- | ---- | ------- | ---------- | ----------- |
| Doe, Jon        | 2007 | Title 1 | Beatles    | The Stooges |
| May, Peter      | 2001 | Title 2 |            | Beatles     |
| Schmidt, Andrea | 1997 | Title 3 | Nick Cave  |             |
```

I’d like to be able to query for `Top Musician in the 2000s` and get an output like

```
| Name        | Count |
| ----------- | ----- |
| Beatles     | 2     |
| The Stooges | 1     |
```

How would you archieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I correct understood, you need this

```
select  count(*), name from (
    select Musician_1 as Name from table where Year >= 2000
    union all 
    select Musician_2 as Name from table where Year >= 2000
) t
group by Name 
order by count(*) desc
```

Comment: This works nice for me and I think it’s the easier answer as I’m able to alter the conditions etc. myself while understianding what I’m doing. I have to look into `union` a bit more  Thanks!

Comment: @kbecker87 - You're welcome, please note, that if `in the 2000s` means years between 2000 and 2010 (according to @scaisEdge), then you should change `... Year >= 2000` with `...year between 2000 and 2010`. Otherwise, this query will give you all records after 2000 year. Happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

you could use an union all

```
  select musician, count(*) from (

      select year, musician_1 as musician
      from my_table 
      union  all

      select year, musician_2
      from my_table 
  ) t 
  where t.year between 2000 and 2010
  group by t.musician
```